# How to detect "When Wi-Fi is available" flow in In-App Update?

Tags: android, in-app-update, google-play-core

My question is about In-App Update's FLEXIBLE case, when the "wait for Wi-Fi" option is chosen. How to detect this state?

The exact flow for context:

1. Application is started, In-App Update FLEXIBLE dialog comes up
2. I choose "When Wi-Fi is available" then press the "Update" button
3. Kill the application
4. Start the application again and continue In-App Update

I use this listener below to listen to events. However, there is no option for this specific event I want to listen to: **"waiting for wi-fi to be turned on pending state"**.

[image]

This is the code that starts or continues In-App Update:
[image]

Is there any way I could detect that "When Wi-Fi is available" has been selected and In-App Update is waiting for Wi-Fi to be turned on? Unfortunately, InstallStatus.PENDING doesn't cover this case :(